# Flutter: GestureHandler and Transform.scale result in small hit box

Tags: flutter, transform, gesturedetector

**Background**

Trying to setup a simple image editor, allowing users to scale and move images around with gestures.

Scaling and moving works well via `GestureDetector`, `Transform.scale` and `Transform.rotate`.

**Problem**

Upon scaling, the user can still scale the already scaled images.

But: The `GestureDetector` does not change the area for performing hit tests.

Problem: The user can use the original hitbox only for manipulating images. It is not possible to scale the image by using the *two-finger pinching gesture* on the extended, outer shape.

**Images**

The first image demonstrates the basic setup.

The second image demonstrates the the result of using a gesture. It shows the small, unchanged inner hitbox. As well as the the resulting scaled and rotated shape.

The filled box is the hitbox. The outer rectangle shows the scaled image.

[image] [image][image]

**Desired Behavior**

Using the *two-finger pinching gesture* on the scaled, outer shape should allow further manipulation of the object.

Instead, the inner hit box can be used alone. But a user expects to use the scaled, outer shape for further scaling and moving the object.

**Code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: GestureTest(),
    );
  }
}

class DrawContainer {
  Color color;
  Offset offset;
  double scale;
  double angle;
  late double baseScaleFactor;

  DrawContainer(this.color, this.offset, this.scale, this.angle) {
    baseScaleFactor = scale;
  }

  onScaleStart() => baseScaleFactor = scale;

  onScaleUpdate(double scaleNew) =>
      scale = (baseScaleFactor * scaleNew).clamp(0.5, 5);
}

class GestureTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const GestureTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _GestureTestState createState() => _GestureTestState();
}

class _GestureTestState extends State<GestureTest> {
  bool doRedraw = false;

  final List<DrawContainer> containers = [
    DrawContainer(Colors.red, const Offset(50, 50), 1.0, 0.0),
    DrawContainer(Colors.yellow, const Offset(100, 100), 1.0, 0.0),
    DrawContainer(Colors.green, const Offset(150, 150), 1.0, 0.0),
  ];

  void onGestureStart(DrawContainer e) => e.onScaleStart();

  onGestureUpdate(DrawContainer e, ScaleUpdateDetails d) {
    e.offset = e.offset + d.focalPointDelta;
    if (d.rotation != 0.0) e.angle = d.rotation;
    if (d.scale != 1.0) e.onScaleUpdate(d.scale);
    setState(() => doRedraw = !doRedraw); // redraw
  }

  void rebuildAllChildren(BuildContext context) {
    void rebuild(Element el) {
      el.markNeedsBuild();
      el.visitChildren(rebuild);
    }

    (context as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    rebuildAllChildren(context);
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          doRedraw ? const SizedBox.shrink() : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ...containers.map((e) {
            return Positioned(
                top: e.offset.dy,
                left: e.offset.dx,
                child: Container(
                  color: e.color,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onScaleStart: (details) {
                        if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
                          onGestureStart(e);
                        }
                      },
                      onScaleUpdate: (details) => onGestureUpdate(e, details),
                      child: Transform.rotate(
                          angle: e.angle,
                          child: Transform.scale(
                            scale: e.scale,
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(color: e.color)),
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100),
                            // Text(e.label, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
                          ))),
                  // ),
                ));
          }).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587

Comment: @pskink Thank you, tried to enlarge the parent ad hoc but not sure how to apply this in my scenario. Will give it another try tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a generic, working example with the hitbox' size matching the scaled widget's size.

The basic structure is as follows:

```
SizedBox (infinite size) # may not be needed
- Stack
  - GestureDetector for each Widget
    - Stack 
      - Positioned, Transform 
        - Widget
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// THE ITEM TO BE DRAWN
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

class DrawContainer {
  Color color;
  Offset offset;
  double width;
  double height;
  double scale;
  double angle;
  late double _baseScaleFactor;
  late double _baseAngleFactor;

  DrawContainer(this.color, this.offset, this.width, this.height, this.scale,
      this.angle) {
    onScaleStart();
  }

  onScaleStart() {
    _baseScaleFactor = scale;
    _baseAngleFactor = angle;
  }

  onScaleUpdate(double scaleNew) =>
      scale = (_baseScaleFactor * scaleNew).clamp(0.5, 5);

  onRotateUpdate(double angleNew) => angle = _baseAngleFactor + angleNew;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// APP
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: GestureTest()));
}

class GestureTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const GestureTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _GestureTestState createState() => _GestureTestState();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// APP STATE
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

class _GestureTestState extends State<GestureTest> {
  final List<DrawContainer> containers = [
    DrawContainer(Colors.red, const Offset(50, 50), 100, 100, 1.0, 0.0),
    DrawContainer(Colors.yellow, const Offset(100, 100), 200, 100, 1.0, 0.0),
    DrawContainer(Colors.green, const Offset(150, 150), 50, 100, 1.0, 0.0),
  ];

  void onGestureStart(DrawContainer e) => e.onScaleStart();

  onGestureUpdate(DrawContainer e, ScaleUpdateDetails d) {
    e.offset = e.offset + d.focalPointDelta;
    if (d.rotation != 0.0) e.onRotateUpdate(d.rotation);
    if (d.scale != 1.0) e.onScaleUpdate(d.scale);
    setState(() {}); // redraw
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ...containers.map((e) {
              return GestureDetector(
                  onScaleStart: (details) {
                    // detect two fingers to reset internal factors
                    if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
                      onGestureStart(e);
                    }
                  },
                  onScaleUpdate: (details) => onGestureUpdate(e, details),
                  child: DrawWidget(e));
            }).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// POSITION, ROTATE AND SCALE THE WIDGET
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

class DrawWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final DrawContainer e;
  const DrawWidget(this.e, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: e.offset.dx,
          top: e.offset.dy,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: e.angle,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: e.scale,
              child: Container(
                height: e.width,
                width: e.height,
                color: e.color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This test case has been helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68360447/12098106

Comment: Thank you!!! The Stack child of the GestureDetector did the trick!
I spent some hours searching for this.

Comment: @testerino You are welcome. Took some time to find the solution, too.

Comment: I have to say that this solution only works if you have only one item. In my case I could not us this. But finally I discovered that using Matrix4 and Transform to scale the Widget makes the GestureDetector hitbox fit the Matri4 transformation.

Comment: @testerino Mh, it works for more than one item for me. I use it in production. Good, that you found a solution.